# My image is not being compressed - what should I do?

Tags: java, android, image, compression

I want to send an image to a server with compress size so I do my code here check it and i creat getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) where i put method beacuse i'm new in android developer please help me

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            imagefilepath = resultUri.getPath();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                uploading = getStringImage(bitmap);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                upload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseBillActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, bos);
    byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Comment: how do you know if it is compressing or not?

Comment: I check in my server is image size is 1.25 MB when I capture image tell me I'm a beginner in android

Comment: how you save it in server?

Comment: By PHP API send to image in my server and save it

Comment: i use Volly to send image to server http://prntscr.com/mn6g23